# Rabl undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

I am getting a "undefined method `iso8601' for nil:NilClass" error for my rabl view

view:

```
collection @appointments
attributes :id
node(:start) { |appointment| appointment.start.iso8601}
node(:end) { |appointment| appointment.finish.iso8601}
node(:title) { |appointment| '<a class="patient-select-link" data-id="'+appointment.patient.id.to_s+'">'+appointment.patient.full_name+'</a>' }
```

controller:

```
@appointments = Appointment.order("id DESC")
```

I can't work out where ive gone wrong! I copied the rabl github page example almost exactly, whatever I do the appointment variable is never defined, although I can confirm that @appointments is defined (bettererrors) and has the correct data

Comment: I guess your @appointments collection must be empty

Comment: @appointments is populated, i confirmed it on the better-errors page

Comment: One of your appointment object doesnot have `start`. I mean the value is nil

Comment: ahh you are right it seems a bad record has crept in, I was distracted by better errors reporting that appointment was not defined, thanks! if you put it as an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be One of your appointment object does not have `start`. I mean the value is nil. That's why it is showing an error.